# Кнопки disnake "ctx"

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Я столкнулся с проблемой,

```
class t(discord.ui.View):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=human.parse_timespan("5d"))
        self.value = Optional[bool]
        
    @discord.ui.button(label="Test", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, emoji="")
    async def Test(self, button: discord.ui.Button, inter: discord.MessageInteraction):
                await inter.response.send(ctx.author.id)
                self.value = True
                self.stop()
```

Это мой код (тест код)
При таком коде у меня ошибки:

```
Ignoring exception in command tet:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/core.py", line 173, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 657, in tet
TypeError: object method can't be used in 'await' expression

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/bot_base.py", line 591, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/core.py", line 914, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/core.py", line 182, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: object method can't be used in 'await' expression
Ignoring exception in view <t timeout=432000.0 children=1> for item <Button style=<ButtonStyle.success: 3> url=None disabled=False label='Test' emoji=<PartialEmoji animated=False name='' id=None> row=None>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ui/view.py", line 385, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "<string>", line 190, in Test
AttributeError: 'InteractionResponse' object has no attribute 'send'
```

И да я писал код на **disnake**

```
import disnake as discord
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**В тексте ошибки всё понятно**

```
AttributeError: 'InteractionResponse' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Что переводится как:

```
Объект 'InteractionResponse' не имеет метода 'send'
```

В интеграции для отправки текста используется `send_message()`.
А также вы используете переменную `ctx`, которая нигде не определяется.

**Итог:**

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(timeout=human.parse_timespan("5d"))
    self.value = Optional[bool]
    
@discord.ui.button(label="Test", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, emoji="")
async def Test(self, button: discord.ui.Button, inter: discord.MessageInteraction):
    await inter.response.send_message(inter.author.id)
    self.value = True
    self.stop()
```